# git --merged missing branches

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm trying to verify that all expected feature branches have been merged into the development branch. I am attempting to use **git branch --merged** and **git branch --no-merged** to do this, but branches that were definitely merged do not appear.

For example, when I enter:

```
git branch -a --merged development
```

As expected I get a list, but some branches that were merged are missing. I know this because I have PRs for those branches showing they were approved and merged.  I can see their merge commits in the repo (Bitbucket) UI as well as in the log.

I thought perhaps **--merged** doesn't list branches that are closed, but the --merged list shows other branches that have been closed.

The merge strategy is set to "merge commit" in the repo settings, not fast forward or squash. I have done **git fetch --all** to be sure I have everything from the remote.

---

Additional attempts

Let's say the merged branch missing from the --merged output is Branch_A, and Branch_B is a random branch also merged to development after Branch_A.

I've tried:

```
git log --oneline Branch_A..development
```

...the result is

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'development..Branch_A': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

but if I try:

```
git log --oneline Branch_B..development
```

..and among the results I see:

```
13a370d Merged in Branch_A (pull request #40)
```

---

I am really scratching my head and hope someone can shed some light.

The goal is a straightforward way to see an accurate list of all feature branches that have been merged into another branch ("development", in this case), whether the feature branches are closed or not.

Comment: Strange I've not seen those `--[no-]merged` commands before. They seem to work fine for me as I try them now. Up to now I used my own one-liner script that shows a list of unmerged commits along with branch name they belong: `git rev-list --all --no-merges --not `git rev-parse HEAD` $* | xargs -L1 git name-rev | grep -oE '[0-9a-f]{40}\\s[^\\~\\^]*' | grep -vE '\\stags/'`, maybe it'd work for you? The $* allows to provide a list of exclusions. If it works ok for you, you could then diff it with `git branch -a` to get what was merged. But sure, I'd like to hear what's up with --merged as well!

Comment: could branch_A be deleted after the merge. At least in Bitbucket server there is an option to remove merged branch

Comment: The answer @max630 gave above is almost certainly right and should be posted as the actual answer. I would bet money that when those PR's were merged, someone ticked "Delete source branch after merging", it exactly explains all the behaviour you described.

Comment: yeah, if they were closed, it'd look like that. I don't remember how's in Bitbucket, but in GItlab there's simply a button "remove branches that were merged", so it's highly probable it has happened here. This is why I didn't look for merged branches. What really mattered for me was if the work on the task was marked as completed in the issue-tracker (jira, redmine, etc), and if there were any unmerged commits pending that relate to that task. We used markers like "[jira#1234]" in commit messages, it was easy to grep the unmerged-commits to see if any things are still pending. In any branch.

Comment: The answer that @max360 seems to be correct as far as the behaviour of --merged, but my question is about verifying that all expected branches have been merged in, including closed branches. If --merged doesn't do it (and it doesn't), then what does? I did some searching and don't see documented anywhere that --merged doesn't include closed branches.

Comment: Didn't finish editing the above comment in time...My point (rather poorly made) was that even though the behaviour of --merged (not including closes branches) isn't documented, that certainly seems to be the way it works. Just wanted to say thanks for all your insights –  really appreciate it.  I'm going to try @ quetzalcoatl 's script and suggestion and see how that works. Will get back to you on that.